# Google AJAX search api

Tags: javascript, search, google-ajax-api

Using the Google AJAX search api

How can I call a search from my own text box?
And parse the results in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

The old API was deprecated in Nov 2010, although it is still available.

You're now supposed to use the custom search API which they've geared towards searching only particular sites. You can actually get it to search the whole web by following the method described here:

http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?answer=1210656

Answer (score 1):

The Google Search API is really well documented. [This](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#CustomSearchForm) looks like something you'd be after, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) for the API, Developer's documentation and samples.

There is also a nice blog [here](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/).